# Why is my project not exporting as intended with GLB to PowerPoint?

Tags: export, shrinkwrap

Hi I have made this map in blender
[image: Map in Blender]

And when I export it as GLB and put it into PowerPoint it looks like this for some odd reason:
[image: Map in PowerPoint]

The other 2 texts are gone only leaving Polarian text which is wrong colour and the very very faint Commorian text on the left side. The texts are using shrinkwrap modifier to be flat on the map.
I'm using the shrinkwrap modifier for the text by the way.

Why is this, can someone please help me?

Here is a dropbox link to the Blender file if needed - https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0h8isic7rqy2ot/untitled.blend?dl=0

Comment: I presume that you have to apply the shrinkwrap modifiers before exporting or at least check the Apply Modifiers setting on the Data > Mesh panel in the file selector when you're saving the glb file.

Comment: Didn't realise I had to do that, I tried that and I tested it and it worked but the only problem is that the text colour doesn't work the text is a very light colour different to the one in Blender

Comment: Might be something to do with this (long) posting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures.

Comment: I checked it out I'm quite new to blender so I don't really understand the solution

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I had to make the base colour, emission and subsurface colours the same.